# Zen cart modifications

Tags: zen

I need all functionalities like zen cart except to buy now process or shoping cart.

Actually I need to build only listing of products,its rating and reviews only.

Is there any method to chaNge it from admin.

Regards
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Zen Cart has a showroom mode that disabled its shopping cart functionality. Go to Admin >> Configuration >> My Store >> Store Status and set it to 1 or 2 depending upon whether or not you want to display product prices.